# how to show info window when we click on circle in react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Circle 
 center={{ lat: LAT, lng: LNG }}>
     <InfoWindow>some text</InfoWindw>
</Circle>
```

The circle is shown on the map correctly, but couldn't find the InfoWindow.

If replaced the Circle to Marker, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you using `react-google-maps`

Resolved this issue in [this way](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/960#issuecomment-498549770), i think there are better ways to resolve it if anyone can share, i appreciate this.
Here is my:

```
<Marker
  position={{ lat: LAT, lng: LNG }}
  visible={false}
  key={key}
>
  <InfoWindow
    onPositionChanged={() => console.log('on position changed')}
    onContentChanged={() => console.log('on content changed')}
  >
    <div>
      <span>Name:</span><br/>
      <Circle
        radius={radius}
        center={{ lat: LAT, lng: LNG }}
      />
    </div>
  </InfoWindow>
</Marker>
```